# How to access a slice of a list in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose items are list. Then I want to access a range of the list.

```
ranges = {"page":[str(y) for y in range(1,100)]}
inds = {"page":0}


count = 0
start = inds[sel]
start = max(start, 0)
start = min(start, len(ranges[sel]-10)
for vi, v in enumerate(ranges[sel][start:start+10]):
```

I get `syntax error` for `for` line, what's the problem?

Comment: The first problem is here: `start = min(start, len(ranges[sel]-10)`. It should be `start = min(start, len(ranges[sel])-10)`

Comment: What is sel?
how does `len(ranges[sel]-10)` work for you? Also, can you post the entire error you got?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco right! The `syntax error` was for the line above it....

Comment: Should I delete the question or leave it as it is?

Comment: Same problem as almost always - missing parenthesis on the line above it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, the syntax error is the missing bracket. Most likely you were looking for:

```
start = min(start, len(ranges[sel])-10)
```